# Big S math symbol representing both sum as well as integral

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, integral

I need a big integral-sum symbol in mathematics environment like the big S symbol that was used by Schiff in his monograph on Quantum Mechanics (McGraw-Hill)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest defining a new operator `\bigs` that is the same size as `\sum` using `\DeclareMathOperator` and the `scalerel` package:

[image]

Schiff uses the same size symbol in inline mathematics as well as displayed mathematics, but I think the bigger symbol for display is more consistent with modern typesetting. That book (or at least the old version I looked at) was very inconsistent about typesetting in general.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}

\DeclareMathOperator{\bigs}{\scalerel*{\textsf{S}}{\sum}}

\begin{document}

We shall use the symbol $\bigs$ or $\bigs_k$ to denote...

The $v_n$ can be expanded in terms of the $u_k$:
\[
v_n(\mathbf{r})=\bigs_k S_{kn}u_k(\mathbf{r})
\]

\end{document}
```